# Firebase Analytics, re-enable Advertising Id collection

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

Firebase Analytics for android has a metadata for the manifest to disable data collection before the user's consent

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

To re-enable collection, such as after an end-user provides consent there is the method

```
setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

To limit only the collection of the advertising id there is the metadata to add to the manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Then, to rehabilitate the collection of the advertising id, after the user's consent is there a dedicated method? Or is it okay to continue to use `setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)`;

Answer (score 2):

`setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)` doesn't influence setting `google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled`. Once you disable advertising id collection in the manifest file, there is no way to enable it programatically.